# how to export data to PDF from dynamic table in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, export, export-to-pdf

I want to export data to PDF from a dynamic table, all the plugins use static tables, I mean by dynamic tables that they are created when I make request to export data and the user can't see these tables .

I need this because the way that the users see the data is different from the way that I want to print .

I'm using AngularJs in front end side and Nodejs in backend side to build my application

I tried to use this package : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-save-html-to-pdf

this is an example from the documentation :

```
<button pdf-save-button="idOne" pdf-name="someone.pdf" class="btn">Hello 
Someone</button>
<!-- below block will be saved as pdf -->

<div pdf-save-content="idOne" >
    Hello Someone
</div>
```

the solution I want is to create and print the data in side the div dynamically when the button is pressed. 
now what is the best practice to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular-UI-Grid Export](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/206_exporting_data) future... It handles dynamic data and has some export futures..

Comment: Thank you I will check it .